# Podcasts that I have played or marked as played on my iPhone are not showing as played when I sync to iTunes and are not being removed

Tags: itunes, ios, data-synchronization, podcasts

Recently (I'm not sure when it started) podcasts that are marked as played on my iPhone (4 hardware, 5.0.1 OS), when I plug into iTunes, the podcasts are still showing as unplayed on the iphone in iTunes, and so they don't get removed.  How can I fix this?

iTunes 10.5.1.42 on Windows.

Comment: Is it possible you're manually syncing podcasts as opposed to letting iTunes calculate which ones to sync? The checkboxes in iTunes' Podcasts tab for your iPhone set manual sync choices. You should be sure podcasts are allowed to autodelete from iTunes, which you can confirm in iTunes > Library > Podcasts > Settings....

Answer (score 1):

This is not an exact answer to your problem, but it helps avoiding it!
I have given up using the Music-App and iTunes for Podcasts. I now use the App Podcaster and I am so happy with it.